# Meteor: Putting files from root client- and lib-folder inside a meteor-package

Tags: javascript, meteor

I need to built an meteor package based on an existing meteor-app. So I created the folder packages and in this folder the new package 'package_anything'.

So my structure is now:

```
.meteor
client
    lib
        helpers.js
        utils.js
    app.js
    startup.js
lib
    router.js
    anything.js
packages
    package_anything
        lib
            client
                public
                    library_1
                    library_2
                templates
                    template.html
                router.js
                subscription.js
            server
                publications.js
            shared
                collections.js
            package.js
```

Now I have problems to get the files, which are now outside of the packages-folder into the package. I know that all files inside of `lib` will be loaded first. So how do I do that inside the package?

Second problem is that I can't put the content of `lib/router.js` inside `package/package_anything/lib/client/router.js`. If I do that the app crashes. But I don't understand why.

**package.js**

```
Package.describe({
    name: 'name:anything',
    summary: 'example package',
    version: '0.0.1',
    documentation: "README.md"
});

Package.onUse(function(api){
    api.versionsFrom('METEOR@1.1.0.3');

    api.use(['templating', 'mongo']);
    api.use(['iron:router@1.0.9'], 'client');

    api.addFiles([
        'lib/shared/collections.js'
    ], ['client', 'server']);

    api.addFiles([
        'lib/server/publications.js'
    ], ['server']);

    api.addFiles([
        'lib/client/router.js',
        'lib/client/subscription.js'
    ], ['client']);

});
```

**UPDATE**
**As an example:**

`lib/anything.js` has the content

```
App = {}
App.Mode = {}
App.Mode._dep = new Tracker.Dependency()
```

Now I bring this simple file to `packages/package_anything/lib/client/anything.js`. And I added `api.export('App')` to package.js.

But this will bring me to the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: Tracker is not defined`, so the app crashes.

Comment: What you've written isn't too clear. If things aren't defined it's because you're not exporting variables or adding files correctly. If you weren't aware of this, lib only loads first in your regular app. In packages, each file is loaded according to the order you've set for it. Also, lib of the regular app is loaded after all packages have been loaded.

Comment: Right now all files outside of the package-folder are loaded first, aren't they? After that the package-files are loaded in the order give by the package.js. Correct?

Comment: See my answer. They aren't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Package files are loaded first. Then your regular files.

Package files can't depend on files in your regular project. Package files can only depend on what you explicitly listed as the package's dependencies.

Comment: Ok, thank you so far. I updated the post with another example. I can't fix this point. Maybe you can explain to me, what I have to take care of with this variable...

Comment: lib/anything.js isn't a package file. You can't export a variable from your regular app. If you're trying to use Tracker in a package then you need to do something like package.use('tracker')